# mySQL - Is there a better way of using many OR oparators in query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a huge members database. Let's say I have 10 names. 
I need to fetch these members' last seen values from members table in a fastest way. I have tried

```
SELECT lastseen FROM members WHERE 
name='Pierce' OR 
name='John' OR 
name='Steven' OR 
name='James' OR 
name='Ernie' OR 
name='Stuart' OR
name='Blake' OR
name='Shaun' OR
name='Pat' OR
name='Lola'
```

But using  many OR oparators in the query is an unprofessional way and slow, are there better methods  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT lastseen
FROM members
WHERE name IN ('Pierce', 'John', . . . )
```

In MySQL, there is even a performance advantage to using `IN` instead of `OR`s.  MySQL will create a binary tree for searching the values (assuming they are constants), which speeds up the processing.

Comment: Thanks, but is it exact search ? If I search John, does it also select Johnny ? <offtopic>Also, I am lucky to be answered by this year's top user of Stackoverflow</offtopic>

Comment: @canertaşdemir . . . It is an exact search, usually exactly the same as `=` (difference can arise if you have different collations, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL's `IN` keyword:

```
SELECT lastseen FROM members WHERE 
name IN ('Pierce', 'John', 'Steven', ...);
```

When using PHP, don't forget to use prepared statements and bound parameters. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php